# How do you parse both 2020-1-7 (no trailing zero) and 1/1/2020 formatted texts to LocalDate?

Tags: java, java-8

I simply do this:

```
LocalDate.parse(date)
```

But with what I'm working on, It's only working for stuff like this:

```
2020-01-07
```

It does **not** work with single digits that have no `0` (e.g. `2020-1-7`) or dates that are formatted with a `/` (e.g. `1/1/2020`).

I need to be able to parse them both to `LocalDate`, but it just throws me this exception instead.

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-1-7' could not be parsed at index 5
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:385)
```

context: parsing a csv with dates to a list in Java

Comment: You need to use the overload that accepts a `DateTimeFormatter` - you'll need a separate `DateTimeFormatter` for each format. (I don't *think* there's a formatter that tries multiple patterns in turn, although I could be wrong.)

Comment: The javadoc is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility of defining a `DateTimeFormatter` that uses several patterns for parsing (maybe even formatting, but I haven't checked that out so far):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example date Strings
    String first = "2020-1-7";
    String second = "1/1/2020";
    // define a formatter that uses several patterns
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-M-d][d/M/yyyy]");
    // parse your dates with it
    LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(first, dtf);
    LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.parse(second, dtf);
    // and print them with the ISO formatter
    System.out.println("First: " + firstDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
    System.out.println("Second: " + secondDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

Output is

```
First: 2020-01-07
Second: 2020-01-01
```

**NOTE**
A `DateTimeFormatter` defined this way using `ofPattern` with a multitude of patterns seems not to be suitable for formatting, because the output of these lines

```
System.out.println("First: " + firstDate.format(dtf));
System.out.println("Second: " + secondDate.format(dtf));
```

would be

```
First: 2020-1-77/1/2020
Second: 2020-1-11/1/2020
```

It obviously uses all the patterns and outputs the date two times using each pattern,
which appears undesired for really many imaginable situations if not for all…